# I wanna know if this is correct or not, if someone can help please!

Tags: contract-law

[image]

I wanna know if this is correct or not, if someone can help please!

Comment: I think it should be "Most contracts are made verbally or in writing" and "Some contracts are made under seal", which means that the last sentence is also wrong. What country is this for?

Answer (score 1):

First up I'm not entirely sure this is on topic here.. but this won't fit in a comment so:

> A contract can be defined as 'an **agreement** between two or more parties to create legal **obligations** between them'. Some contracts are made **under seal** in other words they are **signed** and sealed (stamped) by the parties involved. Most contracts are made **verbally** or in **writing**. The essential elements of a contract are (a) that an **offer** made by one party should be **accepted** by the other (b) **consideration** (the price in money, goods or some other **reward** paid by one party in exchange for another part agreeing to do something); (c) the **intention** to create legal relations. The **terms** of a contract may be **express** (clearly stated) or **implied** (not clearly stated) in the contract but generally understood). A **breach** of contract by one party of their **contractual liability** entitles the other party to **sue** for **damages** or in some cases, to specific performance...

Comment: This indeed is an answer. It's an improvement, but you still have "contractual liability" and "terms" swapped. Neither makes sense in their current context.

Comment: @MSalters Good catch.. that's what I get for not fully paying attention!